# Bind XAML property to codebehind variable

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, xbind

I would like to set properties in XAML from my C# code.
The way I do it, it totally doesn't work.

**XAML**

```
<Page
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="x:bind width_background" Height="x:bind height_background">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="Textbox1" Text="x:bind text_textbox1" /> 
    <Border BorderThickness="1" Height="x:bind height_border" Width="x:bind width_border"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

**Code Behind**

```
namespace Test
{
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
  {

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        int height_background = 500;
        int width_background = 600;
        int height_border = 500;
        int width_border = 600;  
        string text_textbox1 = "string test"     
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The property needs to be a dependency property when it is used for binding. What @lindexi said is correct. Have you checked his answer?

Answer (score 0):

The first you should define the property. The second is you should put the bind express in `{` and please see the code.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text", typeof(string), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    <TextBox x:Name="Textbox1" Text="{x:Bind Text}" />
```

You can find all the code in github

More about bind, please see [Data binding overview - UWP applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart)